# Why is typename necessary in return type? C++

Tags: c++, templates, typename

Given a template class Queue with a nested Node struct.

Why is typename needed in the return type here?

```
template<typename T>
typename Queue<T>::Node* Queue<T>::test() {}
```

The nested struct Node in the template class Queue would be in the scope of `Queue<T>::` without typename.

According to [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords):

> We decide how the compiler should parse this. If t::x is a dependent
>   name, then we need to prefix it by typename to tell the compiler to
>   parse it in a certain way.

But I don't see why it justifies using typename?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While parsing the return type (as defined in the question) we are not in the scope of `Queue<T>` yet. Your reasoning would be correct if you were to write

```
template<typename T>
auto Queue<T>::test() -> Node* {

}
```

The nested name qualifier of the fully qualified function name puts us into the scope of the current template specialization. Here unqualified name lookup finds `Node*` in the current specialization, where it is known to refer to a type.

But while parsing the return type in your question the compiler hasn't yet encountered the "current specialization" where `Node*` can be unambiguously assumed to name a type. All it sees is us writing a dependent name from *some* specialization. As such, `typename` is required. It's no different to us having to write

```
template<typename T>
typename OtherUnrelatedClass<T>::Node* Queue<T>::test() {

}
```

Comment: Oh I see. But I don't get how there would there be ambiguity in the return type? Since you can't perform operations when declaring a return type I believe?

Comment: @csguy It's not about ambiguity in the return type (which particular type it is). It's about ambiguity what exactly `Queue<T>::Node` is. How a compiler should know whether it is a type or, e.g., a static member variable?

Comment: @csguy - It's just the way it was defined up to now. A matter of consistency with the places where an ambiguity was possible. However, you are not unreasonable in your deduction. Such reasoning is why in C++20 this was changed. We won't need to write typename in the return type so much anymore. See [Down with typename](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0634r1.html).

Comment: appreciated ----

Answer (score 4):

[StoryTeller's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60277354/2805305) is correct. I would like to add another perspective.

While parsing `Queue<T>::Node*` in the classical function form (like in your example) you don't know yet *what* you are parsing, you don't know you are parsing the return type of a function, that's why you need to explicitly specify you have a type. (well, as shown in the link posted by StoryTeller [Down with typename](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0634r1.html) you could know, but it requires a more complex parsing i.e. you need to scan ahead to determine you are in a function declaration).

But in the suffix return type when you reach `Queue<T>::Node*` you already determined you are parsing the declaration of a function and now a return type is expected.

Comment: "you don't know you are parsing the return type of a function" makes it much clearer